# Flex popup window

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, air

I am creating modal popup canvas window in a parent page. When I close the popup how do we get notification in parent screen that child popup is just closed. Any event for that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code to show your popup:

```
var popup:MyPopup = new popup:MyPopup();

popup.addEventListener(CloseEvent.CLOSE, function(evt) { 
    PopUpManager.removePopUp(popup);
});

PopUpManager.addPopUp(popup, this, true);
```

Inside your `MyPopup` class, you will have a button for closing the popup.  Simply hook the click event to publish a "CLOSE" event:

```
<s:Button Label="X" click="dispatchEvent(new CloseEvent(CloseEvent.CLOSE));" />
```

I prefer this mechanism over having the `MyPopup` object calling `PopUpManger.removePopUp` (as @Fank is suggesting) because it couples the `MyPopup` component to the `PopUpManager` which I don't like.  I'd prefer the user of `MyPopup` to decide how to use the component.

Honestly, though, these are two very similar mechanisms to perform the same end goal.

Comment: This will good for me to use as I am not using Canvas instead of Titlewindow but you say both perform the same end goal. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is:
I Preffer to use the Popupmanager:

Your Popup:
There is a Button "close" call a internal function eg.closeme

```
private function closeMe () :void
{
   PopUpManager.removePopUp(this);
}
```

in your Parent, you open the PopUp like this:

```
private function openPopup () :void
{
   var helpWindow:TitleWindow = TitleWindow(PopUpManager.createPopUp(this,MyTitleWindow,fale));
   helpWindow.addEventListener(CloseEvent.CLOSE, onClose);
}

protected function onClose (event:CloseEvent) :void
{
   PopUpManager.removePopUp (TitleWindow(event.currentTarget));
}
```

My TitleWindow is the name of your class of cour popup extended by TitleWindow.

BR
Frank

Answer (score 0):

Along with Brian's answer don't forget to detach the event listener.  If you leave the event handler in your main app listening for an event from a child object, the child object will not be garbage collected as something is still referencing it.  This is a common memory leak issue.

```
popup.addEventListener(CloseEvent.CLOSE, popup_CloseHandler);

private function popup_CloseHandler(event:CloseEvent):void{
    event.target.removeEventListener(CloseEvent.CLOSE, popup_CloseHandler);
    PopUpManager.removePopUp(popup);
}
```

Here's a great post about Flex's memory management if you want to delve into that further.

http://blogagic.com/163/flex-memory-management-and-memory-leaks

Comment: Although I agree that it is good practice to unhook events, in this case, what you say is not accurate.  When you hook the event, the popup keeps a reference to the host, not the other way around.  As long as nothing else (ie PopupManager) is keeping a reference to the popup, the popup WILL get garbage collected.  BUT, because this relationship (who references who) is subtle and often confusing (case in point), I agree... unhook events whenever you are done with them.  It is the safe thing to do.

Comment: Ahh yes, after having a second look at what i wrote, I did get it backwards.  Thanks Brian for pointing that out.  In this example it's not needed, but I'm definitely with you in saying that it's always the safe thing to do.